# Подгрузка данных через load Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_video(id){
var id_produckt = id;
jQuery("#displayvideo").fadeIn("slow").load("ajax.php", {id_produckt:id_produckt});}
</script>

<div id="displayvideo">
   <h1>тут текст</h1>
</div>
```

Так вот. При загрузке данных в этот блок - фраза тег <h1>тут текст</h1> исчезает. Получается что оно перезаписывает этот div id="displayvideo". Надо реализовать так что б данные подгружались в конец дива не перезаписывая его.

Вариант о том что бы сначало забрать данные с дива id="displayvideo" а потом после загрузки просто его подгрузить вверх блока - неустраивает.. Есть какие-то идет???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('#displayvideo').append($('<div>').load('...', {...}));
```

Comment: огромное спасибо - то что надо...